# Video production client contract

Tags: production

I currently work as a web developer, but have recently set up a small production company on the side.

I've secured my first project and sourced a crew. Before the project begins, I need to create a contract between myself and the client.

I'm finding it difficult to source a good general contract for video production that I can amend. Can you recommend where I can find such a contract or whether I should write one from scratch? I'm happy to pay for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing one yourself is never a good idea. If you're willing to pay, why not hire a lawyer?

There are places on the net where you can find boilerplate, for example [FilmContracts](http://www.filmcontracts.net/) and [FilmMakerIQ](http://filmmakeriq.com/2009/04/588-free-film-contracts-and-forms/), but if there's real money involved your smartest move is to get local legal advice.